# RevoScaleR functions fail over Rserve on Linux

Tags: r, rserve, microsoft-r

I'm trying to run Rserve on Microsoft R Client and execute RevoScaleR functions over a network connection. I can run non-RevoScaleR functions, but RevoScaleR seems to have some kind of compatibility issue.

I can start an Rserve, connect, and have it execute code that doesn't involve RevoScaleR:

```
> library(RSclient)
> rsc <- RSconnect(port=30120)
> RSeval(rsc, '
+ model <- lm(dist~speed, cars)
+ predict(model, cars)')
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
-1.849460 -1.849460  9.947766  9.947766 13.880175 17.812584 21.744993 21.744993
        9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16
21.744993 25.677401 25.677401 29.609810 29.609810 29.609810 29.609810 33.542219
       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24
33.542219 33.542219 33.542219 37.474628 37.474628 37.474628 37.474628 41.407036
       25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32
41.407036 41.407036 45.339445 45.339445 49.271854 49.271854 49.271854 53.204263
       33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40
53.204263 53.204263 53.204263 57.136672 57.136672 57.136672 61.069080 61.069080
       41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48
61.069080 61.069080 61.069080 68.933898 72.866307 76.798715 76.798715 76.798715
       49        50
76.798715 80.731124
```

But if I try to run RevoScaleR functions, I get a "remote evaluation failed" error:

```
> RSeval(rsc, '
+ model <- rxLinMod(dist~speed, cars)
+ rxPredict(model, cars)')
Error in RSeval(rsc, "\nmodel <- rxLinMod(dist~speed, cars)\nrxPredict(model, cars)") :
  remote evaluation failed
```

and Rserve produces the following error output:

```
> Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  Write error: expected 8 got
```

Strangely, RevoScaleR seems to work intermittently if I put Rserve in debug mode. It also works if I run Rserve on Microsoft R Server on Windows, but Rserve on Windows is deeply limited.

One of my suspicions is that Rserve's forking might be causing issues, but the only fork-related warnings I can find regarding RevoScaleR are about a [thread pool feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r/how-to-developer-manage-threads) that I don't have enabled. I feel like connections with the [BxlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/new-components-in-sql-server-to-support-r) might also be an issue - Rserve doesn't seem to create a new BxlServer on fork - but I couldn't find any documentation about that, and I don't even know if the BxlServer is involved if you're not connecting to SQL Server. GDB shows the SIGPIPE is occurring in SendAndReceiveBxlFnToServer, which sounds like the BxlServer would be involved.

I'm on SLES 11 SP3 and Microsoft R Client 3.3.3.

Is Rserve incompatible with RevoScaleR? If it is compatible, do I need to perform any additional setup over what I would with regular R to make it work?

Comment: Further investigation shows that in debug mode, Rserve starts one new BxlServer on initial startup (but none for new forks). In regular mode, Rserve never launches a BxlServer. Something important is going on with the BxlServer here.

Comment: More investigation shows that Rserve does launch a BxlServer, but then it SIGHUPs and dies around the time Rserve daemonizes. Rserve doesn't daemonize in debug mode, which is probably the cause of the difference in debug mode. I think the BxlServer doesn't play well with Rserve's forking, which is kind of weird considering how recent the article about forking and the thread pool is.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Rserve? Note that MRS comes with operationalisation tools.

Comment: @HongOoi: Interfacing with HANA, which has Rserve connectivity. I don't know if HANA knows how to talk to MRS operationalization; I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's poking at implementation details, but starting the BxlServer manually with `RevoScaleR:::startBxlServer()` seems to fix things:

```
RSeval(rsc, 'RevoScaleR:::startBxlServer()')
```

Rserve's forking mechanism seems to interact poorly with the BxlServer - at least, vanilla Rserve. I'm not sure what the DeployR fork does.